# how to write unit test for render a twig template in symfony 3

Tags: phpunit, twig, symfony

```
public function dashboard()
{
    return $this->render('dashboard.html.twig');
}
```

I want to know how to properly write unit test for this method. I use PHPUnit for writing unit tests.

Comment: It always depends on how the tested object's built. Also you didn't say what you want to test in this method. So in general you've provided not enough information.

Comment: unit or functional test? I suggest you a simple "smoke test" as described in the [best practice here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/tests.html#functional-tests)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @Matteo, you should look at 'Functional' testing in this case. @dragoste has a good point that you haven't provided enough information for us to help you.

Take a look at this blog post I wrote up on using Mink for Functional tests:
https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/using-mink-to-perform-functional-tests-in-symfony3-framework/

Your Functional test could be as simple as:

```
$this->visit('/somePage');
$page = $this->getCurrentPage();
$this->assertContains('<p>some text</p>');
```

You get the idea.